# How can I a get a int from a EditText? I tried this algorithm below but the Android Studio return a error ""

Tags: android, android-edittext

My Java code and my xml code. Please what I am doing wrong?

```
 // Get a value from a editText
                EditText editTextA = (EditText) findViewById(a_edit_text);
                String variableA = editTextA.getText().toString(); //this will get a string
                int a =Integer.parseInt(variableA); //this will get a no from the string and casting in integer
                Log.v("DiagnosticoActivity", "Number a: " + a);

<EditText
                android:id="@+id/a_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="Insira a"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="36dp" />

10-10 11:27:34.916 26195-26195/matheussfdb.dptdedoencas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: matheussfdb.dptdedoencas, PID: 26195
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{matheussfdb.dptdedoencas/matheussfdb.dptdedoencas.DiagnosticoActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                              at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                              at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                              at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                              at matheussfdb.dptdedoencas.DiagnosticoActivity.onCreate(DiagnosticoActivity.java:23)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: Add the error message

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: matheussfdb.dptdedoencas, PID: 26195
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{matheussfdb.dptdedoencas/matheussfdb.

Comment: please add the complete stacktrace to your question using the edit command.

Comment: Jens can you help me out? Do you need more informations?

Comment: I put more information in my question about the error. Is it enough?

Comment: That happends, if the TextField is empty, you you get an empty string and that can not be parsed to an integer.

Comment: when I add a comment in this code  int a =Integer.parseInt(variableA) the error is miss

Comment: When I test the app I put as input some number as 8, or 9... How can i fix this? Thank you

Comment: Two ways, either check for empty string or catch the exception. Your error is 'Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""'

Comment: add try{                int a =Integer.parseInt(variableA); } catch (NumberFormatException e){ //handleException) } ...

Comment: I tried this, see below                                                                  <EditText
                android:id="@+id/a_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="Insira a"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="36dp"
                android:text="1"/>                                                                            It works, But I don't what to show a number 1 in my Edit View and I can't see the value of my variable using v

Comment: @MatheusBarreto see my answer

Comment: @MatheusBarreto see my comment

Comment: PLEASE anybody can help me! How the right code should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int a = 0;
try {
    a = Integer.parseInt(variableA); // will only work on numeric entries
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // handle incorrect text entry here
}
// a will be 0 if exception occurred
```

Jens answered it after my comment

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! It worked, the code looks like this, but the Log.V doesn't work when I puta input in my edti text, how to fix?

```
    // Get a value from a editText
    EditText editTextA = (EditText) findViewById(a_edit_text);
    String variableA = editTextA.getText().toString(); //this will get a string
    int a = 0;
    try {
        a = Integer.parseInt(variableA); // will only work on numeric entries
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // handle incorrect text entry here
    } // a will be 0 if exception occurred

    Log.v("DiagnosticoActivity", "Number a: " + a);
```

Comment: I would like to show my input in the edit text into log.v

Comment: You should not add a new question to your answer

Comment: never use a catch block in this way. Add atleast a log statement to the catchblock

Comment: Use a debugger to find out what is happend

Comment: You're using Log.v and your logcat may not be set to show all verbose output. Try Log.d instead...